# MSSQL How to return only one match

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to find matches in a table with the same data.  For example, I have a list of people with their birthdates.  I need to get a list of all the people in the database with the same birthdate.

```
name    birthdate
Patrick 1971-06-07
John    1971-06-07
Mary    1972-06-07
Ashley  1972-06-07
```

When I run this query

```
select a.name, b.name as name2
from #tmp_duplicates a
join #tmp_duplicates b on b.birthdate = a.birthdate
where a.name != b.name
```

I get:

```
name    name2
John    Patrick
Patrick John
Ashley  Mary
Mary    Ashley
```

I only need it to match once, so I am looking for:

```
name    name2
John    Patrick
Ashley  Mary
```

How do I write the query to only match once?